# add event to all links whose id start with “user”?

Tags: jquery

I am creating some links using a  loop
and the links id is  something like 
user1
user2
user3
user4
user5
in short all links will have the word ”user “ and some integer next?

how can I add click event to  all those links whose id start with “user”?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the [starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$('a[id^=user]').click(function() {

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$('a[id^=user]').click(function(){
  ....
});
```

> Description: Selects elements that
>   have the specified attribute with a
>   value beginning exactly with a given
>   string.